# jQuery live() for removeAttr()?

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I need to use removeAttr on elements that may be loaded via ajax.  Is there a way to automatically do this, similar to the way you can bind events automatically with live()?

**NOTE:  I don't have control over the JavaScript libraries that are doing the ajax calls.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this creates a new event for all elements now and in the future that have your 'undesirable attribute', next we'll trigger it to fire and do its work.

```
$("mySelector").live("myRemoveAttrEvent", function(event){
     $(this).removeAttr("myAttr");
});
```

on the successfull ajax call's function

```
// quick jQ ajax, the important part is on success
$("div").load("url", function(data, status, xhr){
   ..do work..
// this is the important part
   $("mySelector").trigger("myRemoveAttrEvent");
});
```

if you do not have control over all the ajax, you have to piggy back on the user events that Cause the ajax to fire ... this is dirty:
//events you think cause the uncontrollable ajax to fire, e.g change

```
$("*").change()(function(event){
       $("mySelector").trigger("myRemoveAttrEvent");
});
```

Comment: ouch.  Assumption - the ajax runs when a person clicks on form inputs
bind to all events that could trigger your unknown ajax, and include the '$("mySelector").trigger("myRemoveAttrEvent");' in those 
html 4 events:
[link]http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: @Brian altered solution in response to your bolded Q

Answer (score 3):

You can use `complete` option of the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  ......
  complete:function(){
    $('selector').removeAttr('attribute here');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't believe this would work because he's wanting to perform the `removeAttr` on elements that haven't been loaded when he would call `ajaxComplete`, so jQuery won't have any knowledge of them. Also, `complete` is a bad choice because it happens even if the request resulted in an error (and thus, no new elements).

Comment: @coreyward: It is upto OP whether he wants to use `complete` or `success`. It depends on the kind of action to be performed whether requests complete in error or success :)

Comment: Did you seriously just piggyback on my response and downvote it?

Comment: Another problem is that the "ajax activity" is coming from various places, some in libraries that I can't change.  The bottom line is that more elements are coming in after page load and I need to be able to do a removeAttr on them when they appear.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is to handle this at the time those elements are loaded, which would be in the `success` callback for your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  // your details
  success: function(html){
    $('a', html).removeAttr('title');
    $('body').append(html);
  }
});
```

**Update**: If you don't have control of whatever is making the AJAX calls and it doesn't provide any hooks or callbacks, you are going to need to find another event to bind to in order to perform this action. Depending on how these elements are being inserted into the page and exactly what you're doing with them, you might be able to use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this (just a guess):

```
$('body').delegate('p', 'load', function(){ /* remove attr */ });
```

I don't know of any events that are triggered when the DOM or a single element is modified. You can try `load`, but I don't think it gets called in the case of AJAX loaded and inserted elements.