# jQuery: Use live event to add tabindex attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like all new elements with class `.link` to have a tabindex.

Delegate/Live does not seem to work:

```
$('body').delegate('.link', 'load', function(event){
   $(this).attr('tabindex',0);
});
```

Trying to apply this to AJAX loaded elements. And using what I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889538/183181), which suggests the "load" event *may* be possible.

I'd like to avoid using trigger, or modifying the AJAX callback.

Comment: `load` won't work. In fact, no event will work for this. You have to change the tabindex from the success callback of the Ajax operation.

Comment: @bfavaretto exactly what I was hoping to avoid :(

Comment: Well, you can always use [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to setup a global/default complete handler. Better?

Comment: @bfavaretto: that's worth noting, but no.  Anyhow just make the comment an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Done that. My answer includes a bit more info, which *might* give you a sliver of hope.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid using trigger? It seems like a good solution to the problem.

Comment: @hradac: because using trigger would be almost equivalent to modifying the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that **no events are triggered when a new element is inserted into the DOM**<sup>1</sup>. The "solution" (not the one you're looking for, unfortunately) is to set the `tabindex` from the `complete` callbacks of your ajax operations. You may use [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to setup a global/default callback, but that may introduce new problems (such as having to deal with the order events are fired).

<sub>Well, that's not 100% accurate; there are the [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events), which are not implemented consistently across different browsers, and are supposed to be replaced by [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers).</sub>